# How to remove zebra striping from ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Seems like this should be an easy thing to do, but I'm not finding it.  An ng-grid is zebra striped by default, how do I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `style` to override the `zebra` css:

```
<style>
    .ngRow.even {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    .ngRow.odd {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
</style>
```

This will make both rows white. Change it to whatever color you need.

Comment: This kind of worked.  I modified .ngRow.even and .ngRow.odd in ngGrid.css instead of adding it to my own stylesheet. Thanks

Comment: the problem with adding to the own stylesheet (after ng-grid's stylesheet) is that the selected row background (if selection is available) is overrided by white too

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to add the modifications in a stylesheet after the ngGrid stylesheet (ngGrid.css), you should do it this way for avoiding losing `ngRow.selected` class

```
.ngRow.even {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.ngRow.odd {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.ngRow.selected {
    background-color: #BDD5FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to customize your theme and add:

`odd-row-background-color: null`