# How to toggle alternating row backgrounds for even or odd rows dynamically in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

How do you toggle the background color of rows dynamcially using ng-grid like turn alternating zebra stripes on or off?   I want this to be an option for the user.  Is there also a way to change to only highlight prime rows or fibinocci rows dynically, or do I have to use something like this: row.getProperty("even") = "#ff0000";

I know you can set it once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687969/how-to-remove-zebra-striping-from-ng-grid-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about something like this with ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-class-even="{ my-even-class : stripe }"
    ng-class-odd="{ my-odd-class : stripe }">
```

and

```
<button ng-click="stripe=!stripe">toggle stripes</button>
```